# Conflict with using JQuery in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, jquery

I want to use JQuery in magento. When I included JQuery in the code, Prototype is throwing errors at this line.

```
element.attachEvent("ondataavailable", responder);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is causing because Jquery and Prototype is getting conflict.You need to solve this conflict.

1) Create one js file called noConflict.js with the following content.

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
```

and include this file after your jquery.js

2) And you can use this jquery wih the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // your code    
    });
</script>
```

P.S. for more information on solving jquery conflict refer http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-solve-jquery-and-prototype.html

Comment: instead of creating a new file can't I add the $.noConflict(); in my code directly

Comment: yes u can add....