# magento jquery issue how to fix

Tags: jquery

i want to make some custom design tool using fabric.js , my code also uses jquery but problem it that when i include jquery.js i get lost of error dues to js conflict how can i fix it

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60487/conflict-with-using-jquery-in-magento/60488#60488

Answer (score 1):

you can check on console log error. or you can use $.noConflict(); method either replace $ with Jquery.